# Django: what is difference between to set CHOICES in models and in forms?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I think that only defining `ChoiceField` in `forms` is best solution if I'm 100% sure to use `form`, right?.

I mean, I don't have to do like this:

**models.py**

```
class Payment(TimeStampedModel):
    PAY_METHOD_CHOICES = (
        ('card', '카드'),
        ('cash', '무통장입금'),
    )
    pay_method = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=PAY_METHOD_CHOICES
    )
```

**forms.py**

```
class PaymentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    PAY_METHOD_CHOICES = (
        ('card', '카드'),
        ('cash', '무통장입금'),
    )
    pay_method = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=PAY_METHOD_CHOICES
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Payment
```

This is redundant code, isn't it?

In this sense, I can not understand why use `choices` in `models` field...

When does it being used? which case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As in document states https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#choices

> If this is given, the default form widget will be a select box with these choices instead of the standard text field.

So basically `choices` param is used to construct form automatically when you do

```
class PaymentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Payment
        fields = '__all__'
```

It will set form field based on your model.

**Answering comment**

If you need to customize form fields you could use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

```
class PaymentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Payment
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {
            'pay_method': _('New Label'),
        }
```

Comment: If I 100% sure to use `form` and override field(add choices, etc) in `form`, then `choices` in `model` would be redundant, right?

Comment: @user3595632 Yes.

Comment: When I'm trying to edit a specific model field for example if I'm trying to change the label of "pay_method " field in forms.py then what should I do?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Thank you very much, this worked.